# Listbox Value is Null

Tags: excel, vba

The issue is rather simple. The End User will select multiple option (Multiple Select) then this value will populate a certain cell. For some reason, when I try accessing this value, it is always a null. I access it with

```
Cells(n, "E") = ListBox1.Value
```

I do this same process with other controls such as combo box and text boxes and I have no issues.
The listBox comes from the Forms and the options are initialized with

```
With ListBox1

    .AddItem "Intertie Scheduling Change"
    .AddItem "Generation Bottling"
    .AddItem "AGC"
    .AddItem "Operating Reserve Change"
    .AddItem "Generation Biasing"
    .AddItem "Internal IT Outage"
    .AddItem "Area Max Reserve"

End With
```

List Box is set to multiselec . How can I fix this issue? 
Thank you.

Comment: Which `ListBox` item do you wish to deposit in the cell ???

Comment: have a read here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813150/how-to-determine-the-items-that-are-selected-in-a-listbox-control

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I want to populate a cell with the values selected in ListBox1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Sub test2()

Dim selectedValues As String

Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then selectedValues = selectedValues & ListBox1.List(i)
Next i

Cells(1, "A").Value = selectedValues

End Sub
```

There are a ton of different ways to format the output, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful .